# Convert Unix command to run in C# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, perl, visual-studio-2010, curl

How do you download a file from a url with params like the one below where it is parsing out url links

Unix equivalent command would be

```
    curl http://URL | perl -nle 'print "$2" if /(<a href=.*usage\/(.*)">.*<\/a>)/'>project_list.txt
```

This needs to be run from a C# windows form, please be specific as to what code this takes.

Comment: parsing html looks a little brittle to me

Comment: I don't understand the down votes, did I do something wrong?

Comment: Possibly for having the audacity to say you'd rather to something in c# than in perl :-)

Comment: Haha yeah a world of special cases, oh well. Thanks Len

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `new WebClient().DownloadString()` to get the page source, then use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class to download the html file. Then use regular expressions or LINQ to XML if the page is well formatted to parse out the links.

Comment: Nice I used your link in combination with the other answer, I got down voted and now i lost my voting right but as soon as I get it back up you go :)